# What is a way to rewind window.SpeechSynthesis?

Tags: javascript, window, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I know that speech synthesis has built in fuctionality for playing, pausing, and stopping an utterance. But how could I go about rewinding an utterance on a larger piece of text? For example, if a user would be listening to an utterance and there could be a play bar at the bottom that they can slide and it would rewind back to a point earlier on in the text by 30 seconds, etc? What way could I go about implementing this in JavaScript?

Comment: There are a couple ways but pretty involved. You can build a map of `elapsedTime` to word during `boundary` events while the text is spoken. Then use the map to find the right word when the slider changes, create a new utterance starting from the mapped word, cancel the synthesis the play the new utterance. You could also have the slider correlate to characters in the utterance and not use time at all (which of course is dependent upon speaking rate). Lots of record keeping essentially.

Comment: `HTMLAudioElement` makes this easier, but then you need an `HTMLAudioElement.src`.